# sql to retrieve latest record

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a sql table which contains columns

```
rollno,subjectcode,subjectname,internals,externals,credits,year-month,type
```

In the `type` column `R` indicates passed in `Regular`, `V` indicates `Revlauation`, `S` indicates `Supple`.

My question is how to get the record when passes in supple or revlaution.

Ex:

```
Rollno   Subjectcode  Subname    Int  Ext  Credits  year-month  type

 1          12a3        dbms     20    5     0        2015-12    R
 1          12a3        dbms     20   40     1        2015-12    v
 2          12b5        oop      20   2      0        2015-12    R
 2          12b5        oop      20   35     1        2016-02    s
```

I have to retrieve the latest records from the table.
i.e., second record and 4th record.

When i want to get the data of the particular rollnumber i have to get the latest record i.e, here in this example rollno 1 is failed in regular(R) and passed in revaluation (V). so when i retrieving the data i should get the latest one passed in revaluation.

Comment: Define 'latest' - my suspicion is that the data set is not properly representative of the problem.

Comment: Why is the "second" the "latest"? Both rows for rollno = 1 have the same "year-month" value and I don't see any other column that could define a sort order that would enable you to pick the "latest". Queries for [tag:greatest-n-per-group] are typically solved by using window functions

Comment: ...where available